# Is it possible to kill a thread using boost::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

For a program I'm working on, I am trying to add a cancel function which should instantly kill all working threads.

I wonder how this could be realized. I am aware that this might result in a corrupted state.

(I also have access to all of the working threads. I just couldn't find a way to forcefully kill them.)

If it's not possible with the boost::thread libary I do not want to know it!

Comment: Indiscriminate murder of threads is a bad idea. Do what the guy below says.

Comment: What does it even *mean* to "instantly kill a thread"? You can pull the plug of your computer, but I doubt that's what you had in mind.

Comment: I mean you would kill it like you can kill a process/program. Meaning wherever it is it will stop working and no longer exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the answer here:
[Kill a blocked Boost::Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272750/kill-a-blocked-boostthread)

Platform specific code using the native_handle may be your only option.

Comment: Platform independed code was never a goal. As far as it's working for Windows I'm fine!

Comment: @YannickSchinko This should do the trick: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4):

The Best way may be [interruption point](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#interruption_points) . Define it. And you code will stop as far as it achieve the nearest interruption point.

Comment: That's not possible since I'm using libaries which do most of the work. And one function call might take several hours. (Depending on how I set everything up)

Comment: @YannickSchinko sorry, as far as im aware there is no other simple solution. You should set it up in other way.